# Aws lambda function addPermission error: PolicyLengthExceededException

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch

I am creating a cloudwatch event which at a specific time in future is supposed to call a aws lambda function . The i am using aws nodejs sdk as described here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/index.html

the code block to create the cloudwatch event looks like this:

```
 module.exports.createReservationReminder = function (reservationModel, user, restaurant) {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    const ruleName = "rsv_" + reservationModel.reservationId;
    const description = "Reservation reminder of `" + user.name + "` @ `" + restaurant.title + "` on `" + reservationModel.time + "`";
    let reservationTime = reservationModel.time;
    let lambdaFunctionName = module.exports.buildLamdaFunctionArn("restaurant")

    let alertTime = moment(reservationTime).tz(AppConfig.defaultTimezone).subtract( // Create alert 45 minute before a reservation
            45,
            'minutes'
        );

    let lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
        accessKeyId: AppConfig.accessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey: AppConfig.secretAccessKey,
        region: AppConfig.region
    });

    let scheduleExpression1 = "cron(" + alertTime.utc().format('m H D MMM ? YYYY') + ')';

    let ruleParams = {
        Name: ruleName, 
        Description: description,
        ScheduleExpression: scheduleExpression1,
        State: 'ENABLED',
    };
    cloudwatchevents.deleteRule({Name: ruleName}, function (err, deleteRuleData) { //remove if a previous rule was created halfway
        cloudwatchevents.putRule(ruleParams, function (err, ruleData) {  //create the rule 
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
            }
            else {


                let lambdaPermission = {
                    FunctionName: lambdaFunctionName,
                    StatementId: ruleName,
                    Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction',
                    Principal: 'events.amazonaws.com',
                    SourceArn: ruleData.RuleArn
                };

                let removePermission = {
                    FunctionName: lambdaFunctionName,
                    StatementId: ruleName,
                }

                //now to create the rule's target, need to add permission to lambda
                lambda.removePermission(removePermission, function (err, removeLambdaData) { //remove if rule of same name was added as permission to this lambda before, ignore if rule not found error is thrown
                    lambda.addPermission(lambdaPermission, function (err, lamdaData) { //now add the permission
                        if (err) {
                            reject(err) // FAIL : throws error  PolicyLengthExceededException after ~50 cloudwatch events are registered to this lambda function
                        }
                        else {
                            let targetParams = {
                                Rule: ruleName,
                                Targets: [
                                    {
                                        Arn: module.exports.buildLamdaFunctionArn("restaurant"), 
                                        Id: ruleName, 
                                        Input: JSON.stringify({
                                            func: "notifyUserOfUpcomingReservation",
                                            data: {
                                                reservationId: reservationModel.reservationId
                                            }
                                        }),

                                    },

                                ]
                            };
                            cloudwatchevents.putTargets(targetParams, function (err, targetData) {
                                if (err) {
                                    reject(err)
                                }
                                else {
                                    resolve(targetData)
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    })
                })
            }
        });
    })


})
```

}

Above function works fine for the first ~50 times ( so I can easily make reminder for the 50 reservations. ) However , it will always fail eventually with:

PolicyLengthExceededException
Lambda function access policy is limited to 20 KB.

HTTP Status Code: 400

Which makes sense, as policy document can not be too big. 
So what is the correct way to approach this problem : make unlimited cloudwatch event reminder with a lambda function target .

Comment: You're creating an event for each of these that you need to fire?  I don't think that will scale, for other reasons.  It seems like a better strategy would be a single recurring event that fires every 5 minutes and queries a table (e.g. DynamoDB or RDS) to see which un-sent notifications need to be sent "now," and handles them then by invoking a second Lambda function.  Thoughts?

Comment: due to restriction on number of cloudwatch event that i can have, ended up doing exactly that :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a role and add that policy or permission for that role and then your lambda can assume role and run. 
you can use aws [`STS`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/STS.html) module for that.

Rather than create and removing permission each time. STS will assume role temporarily then execute the code.

Comment: This is indeed the correct approach for the problem posed. However, turns out there is a limit on the max number of scheduled events as well ( 100 ) . So ended up doing what @michael-sqlbot suggested